# Generating PMML from sklearn models with GridSearch in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pmml

I'm looking to train models in sklearn and export them for execution to other environments via PMML (using https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml)

I'm able to generate PMML from a normal (k-Nearest Neighbors) model (without GridSearch) but get the following error with GridSearch -

#### TypeError: The pipeline object is not an instance of PMMLPipeline

The error makes sense (since GridSearchCV does not return a PMMLPipeline), but was looking for thoughts on how to export an optimized (w/GridSearch) model to PMML (e.g. is there a way to include GridSearch in the PMMLPipeline).

Code below - TIA for any thoughts.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

knn_pipe = PMMLPipeline([
("regressor", KNeighborsRegressor())
])

param_grid = {"regressor__n_neighbors": [3, 2,10],
          "regressor__weights": ["uniform","distance"],
          "regressor__algorithm": ["auto", "ball_tree", "kd_tree"]}

cv = GridSearchCV(knn_pipe, param_grid=param_grid)

print(train.drop('y',axis=1).shape)

cv.fit(X,Y)

best_parameters = cv.best_estimator_.get_params()
print("best parameter = {}".format(best_parameters))

from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
sklearn2pmml(cv, "kNNMercedes.pmml", with_repr = True)




['regressor__algorithm', 'regressor__n_neighbors', 'regressor__metric', 
'regressor__leaf_size', 'regressor', 'regressor__p', 
'regressor__metric_params', 'steps', 'regressor__n_jobs', 
'regressor__weights']
 (4209, 365)
best parameter = {'regressor__algorithm': 'auto', 'regressor__n_neighbors': 
10, 'regressor__metric': 'minkowski', 'regressor__leaf_size': 30, 'regressor': 
KNeighborsRegressor(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
          metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=10, p=2,
      weights='distance'), 'regressor__p': 2, 'regressor__metric_params': None, 'steps': [('regressor', KNeighborsRegressor(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
      metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=10, p=2,
      weights='distance'))], 'regressor__n_jobs': 1, 'regressor__weights': 
'distance'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-d548c1bff799> in <module>()
 30 
 31 from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
---> 32 sklearn2pmml(cv, "kNNMercedes.pmml", with_repr = True)
 33 
 34 print("yeay PMML!")

/Users/venuv/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn2pmml/__init__.pyc in 
sklearn2pmml(pipeline, pmml, user_classpath, with_repr, debug)
125                 print("sklearn2pmml: ", __version__)
126         if(not isinstance(pipeline, PMMLPipeline)):
--> 127                 raise TypeError("The pipeline object is not an 
instance of " + PMMLPipeline.__name__)
128         cmd = ["java", "-cp", os.pathsep.join(_package_classpath() + user_classpath), "org.jpmml.sklearn.Main"]
129         dumps = []

TypeError: The pipeline object is not an instance of PMMLPipeline
```

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace of error? Also, the knn_pipe you are trying to save is not yet fitted (trained).

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks. I updated the code (and stack trace)

Comment: You can only use a PMMLPipeline object inside that command, hence the error. Can you use `cv.best_estimator_` inside the sklearn2pmml line?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to construct a `PMMLPipeline` instance off the fitted `GridSearchCV` instance:

```
pipeline = PMMLPipeline([
  ("best_estimator", cv.best_estimator_)
])
sklearn2pmml(pipeline, "pipeline.pmml")
```

User @vivek-kumar has reported this issue with the JPMML-SkLearn project, and has received some additional comments there. See [jpmml/jpmml-sklearn#42](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn/issues/42)

Comment: This does not work. The main issue here is about the specific value ("distance) "of parameter  `weights` of the KNeighborsRegressor.

Comment: So, summarizing your discussions from https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sklearn/issues/42 (validated by my own prototyping) - 1. cv.best_estimator_ is itself a PMMLPipeline, 2. 'distance' isn't supported a a weights fn at the moment. So GridSearchCV without 'distance' works when I run it with the permitted weights function, without having to wrap it in another pipeline. thanks for your thoughts

Comment: `GridSearchCV` works with `uniform` weights function, but not with `distance`.  If you pass a `PMMLPipeline` as the first argument to `GridSearchCV`, then there is no need to re-wrap anything (as the `cv.best_estimator` will also be `PMMLPipeline`). But if the first argument is a "raw" estimator, then you need to wrap it as shown above. The original error message "The pipeline object is not an instance of PMMLPipeline" indicates that you are/were dealing with a "raw" estimator, so wrapping is needed.

Comment: Yes, wrapping is needed when `cv` is used inside the sklearn2pmml command. But in your answer, you are using `cv.best_estimator_` and wrapping it, which is not needed.